# XML Deserialization C#, newline character \n is replaced with \\n

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to deserialize a simple Xml Document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
   <somedata> Data1\nData2\n </somedata>
</data>
```

This is my function.

```
public class DataTry
{
    public static string deserialize()
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\myfile.xml");
        object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        Data XmlData = (Data)obj;
        reader.Close();
        return XmlData.somedata;
    }

    [Serializable, XmlRoot("data")]
    public class Data
    {
        [XmlElement("somedata")]
        public string somedata { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The result i get back is Data1\\nData2\\n. 
I don't want the newline character \n to be replaced with \\n.

Comment: `The result i get back is Data1\nData2\n. I don't want the newline character \n to be replaced with \\n.`

This is not clear: are you getting your desired result, yet you don't want that ???

Comment: Sorry I edited the question. I am getting Data1\\nData2\\n

Comment: why don't u just replace '\\' with '\'?

Comment: @Nejdi where are you getting the  double slash?

Comment: @ Alex I don't want to replace every escape character. I am trying to use it in a project which has many escape characters. I want to get the string literal as a result of XML deserialization.

Comment: @DanielA.White when i call the deserialize() method I get back "Data1\\nData2\\n" I want to get back plain text like this "Data1\nData2\n" as it was in the xml file.

Comment: @Nejdi specifically where?

Comment: `\n` will show as `\\n` in the debugger. Are you *sure* it's changed it?

Comment: @DanielA.White Specifically when calling the method in a C# winforms app, using MessageBox.Show(DataTry.deserialize());
It prints out Data1\nData2\n, but I want it to print out newline, like this 
Data1
"should be a newline here"
Data2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115459/xml-deserialization-standardising-line-endings-how-to-stop-it-net

Comment: @CharlesMager i know it will show \n will show \\n but I wanted to have just a newline not \\n. I know it does this because it gets the data and it displays literally what I have written in my XML document. But I was wondering how to change the default behavior. I didn't want to use Replace() because then I should change every escape character that is in my XML. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: @DanielA.White I just wanted to insert newline in my XML document and after the deserialization print them out in a MessageBox in different lines.
Because I have an XML that was not made by me and it contains \n characters. I want to print newlines and tabs whenever a \n or a \t character is in a deserialized string. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is behaving as expected.

Your string is `Data1\nData2\n`.  `\n` here is not a newline character, it is the literal string `\n`.  When you look at this in the debugger, you will see this in its escaped form `\\n`.

If you want this to actually be a newline, you will have to unescape your string.  One way of doing this is do use `Regex.Unescape`:

```
var escaped = @"Data1\nData2\n";        
var unescaped = Regex.Unescape(escaped);
```

See this demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VWphvG

Be wary that this method is intended to unescape regular expressions and will therefore unescape more than just the standard characters.  You can see some other options in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661169/how-can-i-unescape-and-reescape-strings-in-net)

Comment: Yes I understand that it is the expected behavior but I needed to change that. Thank you for your help. This was exactly what I needed.